# Calculus: Volume by rotating curve

Tags: calculus, rotations, volume

R is the region in the first quadrant that is bounded on the left by the y-axis, on the right by the curve $x = \tan(y)$, and above by the line $y = \pi/4$; l is the line $x = 1$.

I came up with the equation so far of $$\pi\int_0^{\pi/4}(1)^2-(1-\tan(y))^2 dy$$

However, I'm not sure if it is right

Comment: Why is there a $(1)^2$ in the integral?

Comment: Because x=1 is 1 away from the y-axis. So I subtract it... there is 2 radii right?

Comment: Is the axis of revolution the line x=1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the axis of revolution is the line $x=1$, then you are integrating along the y-axis and using the disc method. So the radius of each disc is

$r = |1 - \tan y| = 1 - \tan y$ since $0 \le y \le \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

so the element of volume is

$dV = \pi r^2 dh = \pi (1 - \tan y)^2 dy$

and the total volume is $\boxed{V = \displaystyle\pi\int_0\limits^{\pi/4}{(1-\tan y)^2 dy}}$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include the line $x=1$.The formula is $\pi \int_a^b(R(x))^2dx$. In your case, $R(y)=tan(y)$ so the integral should be $\pi \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}tan(y)^2dy = \pi(tan(\frac{\pi}{4})-\frac{\pi}{4}-tan(0)+0)=\pi(tan(\frac{\pi}{4})-\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Comment: But doesn't the curve $x=tan(y)$ bound it, so I thought the area that we rotated was between $x=0$ and $x=tan(y)$?

Comment: You are correct, we are rotating about the y axis so the cross section is bounded to the left by $x=0$ and to the right by $x=tan(y)$. That is why the radius function is $R(y)=tan(y)-0=tan(y)$